# Binary File from script after Tar Issue

Tags: linux, binaryfiles, tar

I was copying a folder from a Debian computer (university specific distro) to a Windows computer. I used `tar` to make a gunzipped tarball containing the folder. I transferred the file using MobaXterm, which used SFTP. I accidentally removed the original file, but I still had the tarball, so I used that to restore.

However, when I looked back in the directory to edit the file `heatmap_get.py` (which was marked executable), it was a bunch of unreadable information. When I tried to execute the script, it stated:

`-bash: ./heatmap_gen.py: cannot execute binary file`

I have tried executing `strings` on the file, but it is not helpful. This tarball contained multiple files, but this was the only one that was effected. I really need this file; any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

If I copied `heatmap_gen.py` to `heatmap_gen.tar.gz`, and undid the tarball, it yielded an exact copy of the directory it was in **except** it did not have the `heatmap_gen.py` file.

Comment: Could you please add more information about the file? what does `file heatmap_get.py` return?

Comment: It says `heatmap_gen.py: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Wed May 25 15:18:43 2016`. I have tried to copy the file to a `.gz` file and gunzip that, but this only yielded a header file (a library I'm using) and then the gobbledy gook again.

Comment: try `tar xf heatmap_gen.py` it should extract the data inside (no need to rename, bash utils often rely on magic numbers)

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: What did you use to extract the original tarball? The only possibilities I see are: 1. the file is corrupted (unfinished transfer) 2. the tarball was not extracted correctly by the utility you used.

Comment: I used `tar` to extract, as well as `tar` to compress.

Comment: You should do `tar -zxvf file.tar.gz` ...

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to include the original "heatmap_gen.py"? So if you extract the original tarball the only file inside it is "heatmap_gen.py"?

Comment: No, all of the files are present within the tarball. But `heatmap_gen.py` is significantly larger than the other non-corrupted script (3353 KB vs 6KB).

Comment: Try renaming `heatmap_gen.py` to `heatmap_gen.tar.gz` and run the command on it again.

Comment: ^ you need to remove the `.py` portion when you rename it, otherwise it overwrites it.

Comment: Sorry, it was `heatmap_gen.tar.gz`

Comment: If it's not present then it probably didn't get archived correctly; good thing is that you only lost one file if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the original tarball was not archived correctly as pointed out by [l'L'l](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499581/lll). It appears that the tarball contained a copy of **itself** within the file `heatmap_gen.py`.